# Numpy で素数の和を求めるには？

Tags: python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n/3035188#3035188 に書かれてあるprimesfrom2toという関数を使って、以下のコードを実行しました。

```
import numpy

def primesfrom2to(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    sieve = numpy.ones(n/3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
    for i in xrange(1,int(n**0.5)/3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[       k*k/3     ::2*k] = False
            sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)/3::2*k] = False
    return numpy.r_[2,3,((3*numpy.nonzero(sieve)[0][1:]+1)|1)]

N = 10 ** 6
print primesfrom2to(N)

total = 0
for i in primesfrom2to(N):
    total += i
print total
```

すると、実行結果は次のようになりました。

```
[     2      3      5 ..., 999961 999979 999983]
150808.py:16: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in int_scalars
  total += i
-1104303641
```

注）150808.py はファイル名です。

10^6 までの素数は求まっているのに、和が求まっていません。
このことを解消するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
（ちなみに N = 10 ** 5 のとき素数の和は求まります。）

（追記）2015/08/08 22:25
total = 0L
となおすだけで上記問題は解決しました。
なお、修正後 N = 10 ** 9 のとき素数の和は求まりますが、
N = 10 ** 10 以上のとき素数の和は求まりませんでした。
これは、Numpy では計算できないことなのでしょうか？

Comment: 前回と同じで `total = 0L` とします。

Comment: あまりにつまらないミスをしてしまいました。

Comment: おそらく、`ValueError: Maximum allowed dimension exceeded` というエラーメッセージが表示されたのだと思いますが、[What's the maximum size of a numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525344/whats-the-maximum-size-of-a-numpy-array) が参考になると思います。`10^9 < 2^32 < 10^10` なので、32bit CPU 版 OS での限界なのでしょう。

Comment: 2^31 よりほんの少し小さい2140000000(> 10^9)のときは求まりました。しかし、これ位までしか計算できないようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

（追記）の
「N = 10 ** 10 以上のとき素数の和は求まりませんでした。
これは、Numpy では計算できないことなのでしょうか？」
に対する回答です。

私の環境は
　OS：Windows 64bit版
　Numpy:32bit版※
でした。
※Pythonによるデータ分析入門1.4.1の訳注に「Windowsが64bit版であっても、64bit版のCanopy Expressが正常に動作しない場合がありました。この場合を回避するために、翻訳時点（2013年8月現在）では、32bit版を利用することをおすすめします」とあったので、32bit版をインストールしました。

よって、Numpyの32bit版という理由で
N = 10 ** 10 以上のとき素数の和は求まらない
と言えそうです。

（おまけ）
N が 10, 10^2, … ,10^9 のときの値を列挙してみた。

```
import numpy

def primesfrom2to(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    sieve = numpy.ones(n/3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
    for i in xrange(1,int(n**0.5)/3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[       k*k/3     ::2*k] = False
            sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)/3::2*k] = False
    return numpy.r_[2,3,((3*numpy.nonzero(sieve)[0][1:]+1)|1)]

for i in range(1, 10):
    print primesfrom2to(10 ** i).sum(dtype=numpy.int64)
```

実行結果
17
1060
76127
5736396
454396537
37550402023
3203324994356
279209790387276
24739512092254535

Answer (score 1):

有限桁の２進表現を使用するnp.int64等では計算できる数字の大きさに限度があります。
任意多倍長で計算する機能はおそらくNumPy自体には含まれていません
（あまり真面目に確認してませんが）。
例えば代表的な多倍長のライブラリである[GMP](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library)のラッパーである[gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)の[mpz](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mpz.html#examples)を使えば

```
import gmpy2
total = gmpy2.mpz(0)
for i in primesfrom2to(N):
    total += 1
```

として正しい値が計算できると思います。